# Android Studio Installation Issues

Tags: android, 17.04, android-studio

When I was trying to install Android Studio, it printed this error and after that if won't work... I don't know what to do

The following SDK components were not installed: Android Support Repository and Android SDK Platform 26

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing Ubuntu Make and then installing Android Studio (that's what I did on 16.04). There's [an article](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make) on the Ubuntu Wiki that covers it, but the steps are:

install Ubuntu Make directly from the Universe archive:

```
 $ sudo apt install ubuntu-make
```

Then use Ubuntu Make to install Android Studio:

```
 $ umake android
```

And that worked for me.

---

***Note***, if you were installing on an Ubuntu version earlier than 16.04 (which you aren't in this case, but this may help others who are) you could install from the Ubuntu Make PPA.

First, add the PPA to your system:

```
 $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
 $ sudo apt-get update
```

Then, install Ubuntu Make:

```
 $ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
```

and finally use Ubuntu Make to install Android Studio:

```
 $ umake android
```

Comment: This does not work on my system. First of all, it says that I need to install "umake android android-ndk", then when I try to download it, it says that the checksum is incorrect.